# Compare two equal arrays but isequal() function return 0 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, video

I have two videos and convert them to arrays in Matlab. Then convert them to three separate arrays for each color as follows:

```
 v = VideoReader('d:\movie_1.avi');
 while hasFrame(v)
       A = readFrame(v);
       r = A(:,:,1);
       g = A(:,:,2);
       b = A(:,:,3);
 end;

v_2 = VideoReader('d:\movie_2.avi');
while hasFrame(v_2)
   A_2 = readFrame(v_2);
   r_2 = A_2(:,:,1);
   g_2 = A_2(:,:,2);
   b_2 = A_2(:,:,3);
end;
```

Then I compared them by **isequal** function:

```
comp_r = isequal(r,r_2)
comp_g = isequal(g,g_2)
comp_b = isequal(b,b_2)
```

All three results are zero that means false:

```
comp_r =
     0

comp_g =
     0

comp_b =

     0
```

But when I took differences between them I didn't get anything:

```
diff_r = setdiff(r,r_2)
diff_g = setdiff(g,g_2)
diff_b = setdiff(b,b_2)
```

and the result was:

```
diff_r =
   Empty matrix: 0-by-1

diff_g =
   Empty matrix: 0-by-1

diff_b =
   Empty matrix: 0-by-1
```

I can't understand the behavior of this test. The `isequal` function return false but `setdiff` function doesn't return any differences.

Answer (score 2):

According to [setdiff](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) it is possible for `isequal` to return `0` and `setdiff` to return `empty`.

> C = setdiff(A,B) returns the data in A that is not in B, with no repetitions. C is in sorted order.

Example:

`setdiff([1,2,3], [3,2,1])` returns `empty`

`isequal([1,2,3], [3,2,1])` returns `0`

You may try the following for finding the difference:

```
r_max_abs_diff = max(abs(double(r(:)) - double(r_2(:))));
disp(['r_max_abs_diff = ', num2str(r_max_abs_diff)]);

%Display the differences of r and r_2 (with false colors):
figure;imagesc(double(r) - double(r_2));impixelinfo;title('r - r\_2');
```